# limit a div only to its own parent

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm doing this output and it's already running like I wanted it to. This is like moving a `div` using arrows keys, but my problem is when I press arrows key to move, the color grey `div` surpasses its own parent `div`. What I want to achieve is that the grey `div` would not be able to step outside its parent `div` (that has a red border), even if I continually press arrow keys.

This is demo [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4bpgp/15/)

Any help?

Comment: in jsFiddle I don't see any grey div.. Can you check it?

Comment: i think you need to change the framework from the left side and make it jQuery? i'm sorry for my mistake..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to

```
$(function(){
    var spaceship = $('<div id="spaceshipContainer"/>'); // store reference to actual jQuery object
    var cS = $('#centerSpace').append(spaceship);
    var limits = {width: cS.width()-spaceship.width() , height:cS.height()-spaceship.height()}; // pre-calculate the limits

    $(document).keypress(function(e){
        var position = $('#spaceshipContainer').position();


        switch(e.keyCode){

            case 37:
                position.left -= 10;
                break;
            case 38:
                position.top -= 10;
                break;
            case 39:
                position.left += 10;
                break;
            case 40:
                position.top += 10;
                break;
        }

        position.left = Math.max(Math.min(position.left, limits.width),0); // enforce horizontal limits
        position.top = Math.max(Math.min(position.top, limits.height),0); // enforce vertical limits

        spaceship.css({left:position.left, top:position.top});
    });
});
```

Also add `position:relative` to the `#centerSpace`

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/4bpgp/17/

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#constrain-movement) on jQuery?

Comment: what i want is to use arrow keys to move the div and not to drag it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the containers position and check that the position of the grey box doesn't exceed it.

Here you go the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mahsa_999/4bpgp/39/) working example.

```
$(function(){
var spaceship = '<div id="spaceshipContainer"></div>';
$('#centerSpace').append(spaceship);
var parent_position = $('#centerSpace').position();
var parent_right = parent_position.left + $('#centerSpace').width() -$('#spaceshipContainer').width();
var parent_buttom= parent_position.top + $('#centerSpace').height()-$('#spaceshipContainer').height();
$(document).keypress(function(e){

    var position = $('#spaceshipContainer').position();

    switch(e.keyCode){

        case 37:

            if( position.left - 10 >= parent_position.left)
                $('#spaceshipContainer').css('left', position.left - 10 + 'px');
            break;
        case 38:
            if( position.top - 10 >= parent_position.top)
            $('#spaceshipContainer').css('top', position.top - 10 + 'px');
            break;
        case 39:
            if( position.left  <= parent_right)
            $('#spaceshipContainer').css('left', position.left + 10 + 'px');
            break;
        case 40:
            if( position.top<= parent_buttom)
            $('#spaceshipContainer').css('top', position.top + 10 + 'px');
            break;
    }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On your keypress callback, you simply add some logic like this:

```
var $ship = $('#spaceshipContainer');

if ($ship.offset().top < $ship.parent().offset().top) {
    return false;
}
// repeat for left, right, bottom
```

I picked `offset` so the x/y coordinates would be relative to the document.